# Spark Parquet read error : java.io.EOFException: Reached the end of stream with XXXXX bytes left to read

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

While reading parquet files in spark, if you face the below problem.

---

App > Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 44, 10.23.5.196, executor 2): java.io.EOFException: Reached the end of stream with 193212 bytes left to read
App > at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:104)
App > at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFullyHeapBuffer(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:127)
App > at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:91)
App > at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1174)
App > at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:301)
App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:256)
App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:124)
App > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:215)

---

For below spark commands:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://.../file.parquet")
df.show(5, false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can bypass this issue with

```
--conf  spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader=false
```

Comment: Careful here because it could increase the speed of reading your files significantly https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12854

Answer (score 9):

For me [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246260/5246670) didn't do the trick, but the following did:

```
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.experimental.input.fadvise=sequential
```

Not sure why, but what gave me a hint was [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16109) and some details about the options [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3-get-requests.html).

Comment: This didn't help me, I am using parquet with iceberg.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting below set of Exceptions in different spark apps:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Reached the end of stream with 1008401 bytes left to read
    at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:104)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFullyHeapBuffer(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:91)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: could not read page in col [X] optional binary X (UTF8) as the dictionary was missing for encoding PLAIN_DICTIONARY
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.initDataReader(VectorizedColumnReader.java:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readPageV1(VectorizedColumnReader.java:616)
```

Setting this spark config

```
--conf  spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader=false
```

solved both the issues.